# Why does my outer variable not change when using a while loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function ranNum(value) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * value)
}

function createRanId(value) {
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
  const numbers = '0123456789'.split('')
  const idLength = value || 6
  let id = ''

  for(let i = 0; i < idLength; i++) {
    const numOrAlpha = ranNum(2)

    numOrAlpha === 1 ? id += alphabet[ranNum(alphabet.length - 1)] : id += numbers[ranNum(numbers.length - 1)]
  }

  return id
}

function isAllNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.every(value => Number.isInteger(value))
}

function allNumberId() {
  let count = 0
  let ranNum = createRanId(2).split("");

  while(!isAllNumbers(ranNum)) {
    ranNum = createRanId(2).split("")
    count++
  } 


  return [count, ranNum]
}

console.log(allNumberId())
```

So what im doing is generating a random string that consists of numbers and letters (for example: 3e3jjf). What i'm trying to achieve is to find a generated combination that only consists of numbers (for example: 235033). However, my code doesnt seem to work and ends up in an infinite loop. I'm making a thinking error somewhere in the function `allNumberId`

edit: this is obviously not production code or anything. I'm just practicing some  javascript. It bugs me that I cant find what I do wrong here.

Comment: Well maybe it never generates one that is all numbers....

Comment: It does, I've tested it manually

Comment: If you want it to be all numbers, why are you generating it with alphabetic characters at all?  Why not just generate it with only digits, then you can simply remove the "is every character a digit" check entirely, and not have to worry about long-running loops.

Comment: Number.isInteger("6") A sting is not a number

Comment: For no particular reason other than Javascript practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are checking for a number

```
Number.isInteger("6")
```

When it is a string it is false. So you need to alter your code to try to make it into a number or other option is `isNaN()`

```js
function ranNum(value) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * value)
}

function createRanId(value) {
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
  const numbers = '0123456789'.split('')
  const idLength = value || 6
  let id = ''

  for(let i = 0; i < idLength; i++) {
    const numOrAlpha = ranNum(2)

    numOrAlpha === 1 ? id += alphabet[ranNum(alphabet.length - 1)] : id += numbers[ranNum(numbers.length - 1)]
  }

  return id
}

function isAllNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.every(value => Number.isInteger(+value))
}

function allNumberId() {
  let count = 0
  let ranNum = createRanId(2).split("");

  while(!isAllNumbers(ranNum)) {
    ranNum = createRanId(2).split("")
    count++
  } 


  return [count, ranNum]
}

console.log(allNumberId())
```

Your check could also be done as

```
const isInvalid = yourString.split("").map(Number).some(isNaN)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed! I dont understand why I need to add the '+', could you clarifiy that a bit more? What is the + doing?

Comment: basically same thing as Number() or parseFloat()

Comment: Ahhh, so my numbers were seen as strings and not as numbers.... Oh boy..

Comment: Because you removed them from a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the usage of [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger). You're actually passing strings there (single-character strings consisting of a digit or a alphabet char), which is never a number (integer or not) so `Number.isInteger` always returns `false` and your `isAllNumbers` function doesn't recognice what it should.

Comment: That is correct indeed. I see it now as well. I'm so stupid lol